# Apache can't load a web page after stopping in mac

Tags: macos, mac, webserver, apache-http-server, osx-yosemite

I have Mac OS X 10.10. I configured my Apache to load web pages from Sites folder so when I boot my system Apache correctly loads my web pages from Sites Folder.

When I type

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

System gives me this:

```
_www  337   0.0  0.0  2544588   7660   ??  S     4:09am   0:00.03 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
_www  157   0.0  0.0  2544588   7980   ??  S     4:09am   0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
root   52   0.0  0.1  2544076  15692   ??  Ss    4:09am   0:00.47 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
hasan_azimi0     1691   0.0  0.0  2432772    644 s000  S+    1:38pm   0:00.00 grep httpd
```

Everything works until I stop apache with:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

After I stop apache when I start it with:

```
sudo apache start
```

My browser won't load any page. When I type:

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

There is only one process which is:

```
root   52   0.0  0.1  2544076  15692   ??  Ss    4:09am   0:00.47 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
hasan_azimi0     1691   0.0  0.0  2432772    644 s000  S+    1:38pm   0:00.00 grep httpd
```

I won't be able to load anything until I reboot my System. So basically Apache runs in the startup but after I stop it It can't start it again. I realised there are two processes with `_www` that should be started with `sudo apache start` but I don't know how? By the way I also know that Apache will be started with a file called `org.apache.httpd.plist` So this is the content of it. Please let me know if it's OK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Disabled</key>
<true/>
<key>Label</key>
<string>org.apache.httpd</string>
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>XPC_SERVICES_UNAVAILABLE</key>
    <string>1</string>
</dict>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/sbin/httpd</string>
    <string>-D</string>
    <string>FOREGROUND</string>
</array>
<key>OnDemand</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: And if `sudo service apache2 restart` is issued?

Comment: No what is that? For apache2 and service I have command not found. Never used them before.